# Isolated broadcast segment with docker network

Tags: docker, multicast

I have an application that uses multicast to discover other nodes. Multicast for IPv4 works when the nodes are in the same broadcast segment.

I want to simulate the following scenario:

- node 1 is in network A
- node 2 is in network B
- node 3 is in networks A and B

The expected behavior is that node 3 receives packets from node 1 and 2 using its two network interfaces, while node 1 and 2 receive packets only from node 3.

What I observe, however, is that node 3 receives packets only from node 2, but from both network interfaces.

This is my setup:

```
docker network create --subnet 172.100.0.0/24 net1
docker network create --subnet 172.200.0.0/24 net2
docker run --name node1 --net net1 busybox
docker run --name node2 --net net2 busybox
docker create --name node3 busybox
docker network disconnect bridge node3
docker network connect net1 node3
docker network connect net2 node3
docker start node3
```

I have tried other network drivers (ipvlan, macvlan) but it doesn't make any difference.

Comment: I can confirm that docker networks _are_ isolated in terms of broadcast segment. The issue was my application:
(1) I had one receiving socket per network interface - actually 1 is enough, and
(2) more importantly, I have to send `IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP` for each interface's IP, not just one for all with `INADDR_ANY`.